# Reload new data into token input dynamically and also change the prepopulate option

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, tokenize

I am using jQuery Tokeninput by James Smith. Once I initialize the token input, I need to change the data fed to it and also change the prepopulate option under script control. How can I do this?

Here is my code :

### Initialization:

```
   $('#nameList').tokenInput(data, {
           theme: "facebook",
          preventDuplicates: true
        });
```

Later in the script, I want to change the value of the local "data" and also add prepopulate to it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

you can give the url to your server side script where you get all the required data and send it as json...

> Create a server-side script (PHP, Rails, ASP.net, etc) to generate your search results. The script can fetch data from wherever you like, for example a database or a hardcoded list. Your script must accept a GET parameter named q which will contain the term to search for. E.g. http://www.example.com/myscript?q=query

you can go through the documentaion [here](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#nameList").tokenInput("http://www.example.com/myscript");
})
```

and your result in server side should return in json like

PHP (if your are using PHP...)

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

example

```
[
   {"id":"856","name":"House"},
   {"id":"1035","name":"Desperate Housewives"},
    ...
]
```

Comment: This is not was OP is asking.